# Ternary search won't return answer

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, ternary-search

I have written the following code for a recursive ternary function:

```py
def ternary_search(start,stop,x,arr):
    pos1 = start + (stop-start)//3
    pos2 = stop - (stop - start)//3
    
    if (pos1<=pos2):
        val1 = arr[pos1]
        val2 = arr[pos2] 

        if val1 == x:
            print(pos1)
            return pos1
        elif val2 == x:
            print(pos2)
            return pos2

        if x < val1:
            ternary_search(start,pos1-1,x,arr)
        elif x > val2:
            ternary_search(pos2+1,stop,x,arr)    
        else:
            ternary_search(pos1+1,pos2,x,arr)
    else: 
        return -1
```

I am not getting a return value even though the code is running fine.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(1,100,5) # array([ 1,  6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56, 61, 66, 71, 76, 81, 86, 91, 96])
pos = ternary_search(0,len(a),86,a)
print(pos == None)
```

Output:

```
17

True
```

Comment: What return value did you mean?

Comment: The position of the element. The code is correctly printing it to be 17. I want it to return the value too so that `pos` =  17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add `return` when calling the function

```
if x < val1:
    return ternary_search(start,pos1-1,x,arr)
elif x > val2:
    return ternary_search(pos2+1,stop,x,arr)    
else:
    return ternary_search(pos1+1,pos2,x,arr)
```